# Adding static library to existing project in Xcode 4. Unable to import header

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, static-libraries

I'm trying integrate [Kal](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal) into my existing app. I've followed [this](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/04/using-open-source-static-libraries-in-xcode-4/) tutorial, and I'm still having issues. When I create a new view and import Kal.h, I get an error stating Kal.h is not found. I'm using Xcode 4.2. I've been searching everywhere, and I haven't found an adequate solution.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check in your target->Build Phase->Compiled Source Library, that file exists? look at my existing answer which is co-related to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931510/apple-mach-o-linker-errors-20-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7/9931571#9931571

Comment: Praveen-K, the file does exist in Compiled Source Library.

Comment: Are you setting the header path in your project settings ?

Comment: Yes, using $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)

Comment: First of all i will say remove that entry from project and target settings and try and if it does not work otherwise use the correct path. $(PROJECT_DIR) will be your project directory path. I am 100 % sure it will work. let me know if it works.

Comment: I'm uncertain how that would solve my problem. With that said, I've tried it, and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: That will solve your problem certainly. did you follow the same which i mentioned in my comments.

Comment: Praveen-K, I don't get what you mean either. Remove entry? Which entry? You mean $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)? And this entry also exist in the target settings? What? So if you use  $(PROJECT_DIR) instead of  $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR) this would solve the problem? No it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You can try my blog [post](http://muthukumarela.wordpress.com/2012/05/24/ios-static-libraries-without-adding-header-files/) here.

At the same time you have to add the .a file (Static Library build) into this project.