# How do I resolve 'abt_utf8_nextCharSafeBody' crash

Tags: ios, crash, splunk

I've seen around 177 occurrences for this.

This is the stacktrace I got from Splunk Mint.

Any workaround for this crash?

Happens mostly on iOS 8.3

```
0   IOKit   IOServiceAddInterestNotification (in IOKit) + 44
1   UIKit   _MatchedBatteries (in UIKit) + 100
2   UIKit   -[UIDevice setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:] (in UIKit) + 208
3   Earthmiles  -[DataFixture appendBaseValues] (in Earthmiles) + 2180
4   Earthmiles  -[DataFixture init] (in Earthmiles) + 80
5   Earthmiles  -[NetworkDataFixture init] (in Earthmiles) + 56
6   Earthmiles  SplunkNSURLConnectionSendSynchronousRequestReturningResponseError (in Earthmiles) + 164
7   Earthmiles  abt_utf8_nextCharSafeBody (in Earthmiles) + 41984
8   libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib) + 24
9   libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib) + 16
10  libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib) + 1448
11  libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_queue_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib) + 132
12  libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib) + 720
13  libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_worker_thread3 (in libdispatch.dylib) + 108
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 816
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
```

Comment: Have you tried added `libicucore.dylib` to your project as suggested here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264231/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-utf8-nextcharsafebody-referenced-fr ?

Comment: I did didn't really help

Comment: @bkvirendra did you find a fix?

Comment: @Adriana Are you making use of the Splunk library for tracking crashes?

Comment: No, I'm not, I'm using crittercism/Apteligent. How did you fix it?

Comment: @Adriana Maybe you should try including the libicucore.dylib framework in your project? Let me know if that works.