# Getting "_utf8_nextCharSafeBody" error

Tags: ios, objective-c, mixpanel

I'm attempting to use MixPanel's iOS SDK to track a user action, and I'm receiving the following error when I try compiling:

```
   Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_utf8_nextCharSafeBody", referenced from:
          _validate_dispatch_data_partial_string in MPWebSocket.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

As far as I can tell from the [documentation](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/ios) setup instructions, I've added the framework correctly. This error message doesn't seem to be unique to MixPanel, so I'm wondering what causes this in general, and what aspect of the SDK have I incorrectly integrated?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264231/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-utf8-nextcharsafebody-referenced-fr

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've fixed this issue by adding `libicucore.dylib` in my project under *Link binary with Libraries*. Here is an
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6PAk.png) showing exactly how is should look.

Comment: importing libicucore.tbd fixes the problem as well

Comment: thanks . This helped me after lot of mental torture.